# Android 11 - Webrtc VOIP calls are not working with browser or desktop app. Same is working with Android 10

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle, voip-android, android-webrtc

Good day team!!!

I am developing a calling system, In this case we are working on Android, IOS and web/Desktop platforms.

Audio and Video calls were working fine for Android, IOS and Web/Desktop. Until I have upgraded the Android API level to 30 (Android 11, as its mandatory to update app on to Play Store). Once I switch API level to 30. Android to Android, Android to IOS audio/video calls are working fine.

But Android to Web and vice versa is not working.

I am getting ICE server state as `CHECKING` whenever I am try to connect. After waiting for sometimes its going in to `FAIL` state.

If I switch Android API level to 29 again, everything is working fine.

What could be the issue with new Android API level 30 for VOIP calls using WEBRTC.
I am using `implementation "io.pristine:libjingle:11139@aar"` as lib dependency for WebRTC.

Anyone come across this issue? Please let me know I am stuck with this part.

I am not able to share the code due to huge code for this, If needed specific code, let me know in comment I will provide that. Hope you can understand.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: you are using a package from 2015 that has not been updated since... https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/pristine/libjingle/11139/

Comment: Thank for replaying, I have observe that. I tried to generate the new jar from the https://github.com/threema-ch/webrtc-build-docker. Got syntax error in code itself. So its failed. Do you have any other latest jar or related solution? Please send me if you have anything.